# Partly filling TableView cell with color

Tags: iphone, ios, colors, tableview, cell

In my app I have tableview and I want to fill tableView cell with color depending on core data's data. For example, if a cell contain a value 50, I fill half cell with color. If the cell contain a value 25, I fill quater cell with color and so on.
So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give a solution to your problem.

Add a custom view to the table vie cell

if ur value 50 means,

```
int wd = 50/100*width of tableviewcell;
CGRect rv= CGRectMake(0, 0, wd, height of tableviewcell);
UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rv];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourneededcolor];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:v];
```

and don't forget to set the background color of `uitableviewcell` to `clearcolor`.

Comment: Thanks, good solution. But I have some problems with showing text in the cell. So if I write cell.textLabel.text=smth and then call [[cell contentView] addSubview:v] I see only this view, not text. But if I write [[cell contentView] addSubview:v] before assign the label text property it looks nice, BUT when I scroll the view text disappear from the cell and I can see only area filled with color. Who can I overcome this?

Comment: ur qn is about color, if u had problems with showing the text means post the code

Comment: posting the code will stop the downvotesand the qn will never be closed, remember it